# fread returns 0 and cannot open db file on Windows machine. Can the file not be found? Or is it the permissions?

Tags: c, windows, fopen, fread

I'm doing a tutorial on C ([Learn C The Hard Way: Ex17](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html)) and in the  Database_load function when fread loads the db file "ERROR!  Failed to load database." is thrown. Why can't the db be read? The file is in the directory. Can the file not be found? Or do the permissions need to be changed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_DATA 512
#define MAX_ROWS 100

struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char name[MAX_DATA];
    char email[MAX_DATA];
};
struct Database {
    struct Address rows [MAX_ROWS];
};
struct Connection {
    FILE *file;
    struct Database *db;
};
void die (const char *message)
{
    if(errno) {
        perror(message);
    } else {
        printf("ERROR!\t%s\n", message);
    }

exit(1);
}
void Address_print(struct Address *addr)
{
    printf("%d %s %s\n", addr->id, addr->name, addr->email);
}
void Database_load(struct Connection *conn)
{
    // Error shows up here!
    int rc = fread(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);
    if(rc != 1) {
        die("Failed to load database.");
    }
}
struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode)
{
    struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));

    if(!conn){
        die("Memory error.");
    }

    conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));

    if (!conn->db) {
        die("Memory error");
    }

    if(mode == 'c') {
        conn->file = fopen(filename, "w"); // Problem is here! See @fluter's solution

    if (conn->file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open failed, errno %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

} else {

    conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+"); // And the problem is here!

    if (conn->file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open failed, errno %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        Database_load(conn);
    }
}

if(!conn->file){
    die("Failed to open the file.");
}
    return conn;
}
void Database_close(struct Connection *conn)
{
    if(conn) {
        if(conn->file) fclose(conn->file);
        if(conn->db) free(conn->db);
        free(conn);
    }
}
void Database_write(struct Connection *conn)
{
    rewind(conn->file);

    int rc = fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);

    if(rc != 1) {
        die("Failed to write database.");
    }

    rc = fflush(conn->file);

    if(rc == -1) {
        die("Cannot flush database.");
    }
}
void Database_create(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        // make a prototype to initialize the address
        struct Address addr = {.id = i, .set = 0};

        // then assign the prototype to the database
        conn->db->rows[i] = addr;
    }
}
void Database_set(struct Connection *conn, int id, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    struct Address *addr = &conn->db->rows[id];

    if (addr->set) {
        die("Address already set, delete it first");
    }

    addr->set = 1;

    // WARNING!! Strncpy has a bug - needs to be fixed ...
    char *res = strncpy(addr->name, email, MAX_DATA);

    if(!res) {
           die("Name copy failed.");
    }

    // ... by adding NULL to the end of the array
    addr->name[sizeof(addr->name)-1] = '\0';

    res = strncpy(addr->email, email, MAX_DATA);

    if(!res) {
        die("Email copy failed.");
    }
}

void Database_list(struct Connection *conn)
{
    int i = 0;
    struct Database *db = conn->db;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        struct Address *cur = &db->rows[i];

        if(cur->set) {
            Address_print(cur);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){


if(argc < 3) {
    die("USAGE: ex17.exe <dbfile> <action> [action params]");
} 

char *filename = argv[1];
char action = argv[2][0];

struct Connection *conn = Database_open(filename, action);

int id = 0;

if(argc > 3) {
    id = atoi(argv[3]);
}

if(argc > MAX_ROWS) {
    die("There aren't that many records");
}

switch(action) {
    case 'c':
        Database_create(conn);
        Database_write(conn);
        break;
    case 's':
        if(argc != 4) {
            die("Id, name, and email address are needed.");
        }

        Database_set(conn, id, argv[4], argv[5]);
        Database_write(conn);
        break;
    case 'l':
        Database_list(conn);
        break;
    default:
        die("\tInvalid action.\n\
                \tPlease use:\n\
                \tPlease use:\n\
                \tc = create\n\
                \td = delete\n\
                \tl = list\n\
                \ts = set\n");
    }
Database_close(conn);
return 0;
}
```

The thing is, even though the error says "Failed to load database.", the file is definitely in the folder.

[image: Screen Shot ex17_exe]

I'm wondering if it's the permissions (see above screen shot). For me, I have rw, but Admin has only r. As I'm running the terminal, it shouldn't be that because Admin doesn't have  w, should it?

Comment: The `die` call in your `Database_load` function has the message "Failed to load database" but your error message says "Failed to open the file". The error isn't where you think it is.

Comment: I think it has to be `ex17.exe db.dat`. Or what's up with the `|` (or whatever that character is)?

Comment: @ Colonel Thirty Two, you're right. The error is happening in conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+"); Later on I have:

if(!conn->file){
  die("Failed to open the file.");
 }

Comment: @cremno, the character is a lower case L. I've set up MinGW on my Windows machine, so I can use Linux like commands i.e. ls -l

As for db.dat,  it is fine. It was created by  fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file); and it quite happily opens in Vim.

Comment: The yen symbol in your directory prompt is suspicious

Comment: According to the code posted, `ex17.exe l db.dat` attempts to open a file named `l`, not a file named `db.dat`.  Looks like you've got the arguments the wrong way around.

Comment: How are you ggeting `conn->file address:` in your output, when your source code does not contain any line saying that?

Comment: @ M.M, I'm on a Japanese machine. In a terminal, forward slashes are displayed as ￥(yen) symbols. The same is true in file paths in Explorer.

Comment: @Harry Johnston,  good eye. For this programme, the terminal command pattern is ex17.exe <dbfile> <action> [action params]. To double check, I ran    ex17.exe l db.dat but I got ERROR!  Failed to load database.

Comment: You definitely want to learn how to use a debugger and then use it to step through the code inspecting all relevant variables to understand what is really going on.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, Yu Hao, EdChum, Vin, Rad Lexus - please take a look again at the question and reconsider your decision to consider this off topic. It has been re-worded to match the problem that Linux users have with Windows and to better help other Stackoverflow users find the given solution. On Linux, half the time the problem is the permissions. In addition, the typo entered into the command line is not given in the question now. Finally the code has been trimmed down.

Comment: I'd already voted to reopen following revision #5 or thereabouts.  It'll be in the reopen queue, so it's up to the voters there.  You might want to edit the title and opening paragraph, which still inaccurately suggest that you're getting a "file not found" error.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, it's not for me that I'm fighting for this question, but for fluter. He should get credit for all the patient help he gave me.  And for other programmers that will get this kind of problem. If this question is pulled or has a negative score they will not find fluter's quick and easy solution.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure that anyone with a similar issue will be likely to find this question; after all, you didn't find [any of the already existing answers about it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+%5Bc%5D+is%3Aanswer+binary+mode).  So I wouldn't worry too much about it if I were you. :-)  At any rate, there's nothing more I can do, we'll just have to wait and see if it gets enough reopen votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are printing the address of conn->file, not conn->file itself, of course the address of conn->file is not NULL. So try the following:

```
printf("conn->file address: %p\n", conn->file);
```

This will print NULL if the open failed, and for the exactly error, print errno to find out the root cause of the error:

```
if (conn->file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "open failed, errno %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno);
} else {
    // open db
}
```

For the failures on windows, it is because Windows treat text and binary opened files directly, while on Linux, they are the same. If the file is opened in text mode, windows will convert CRLF into LF and treat ctrl-z control character as EOF mark, this is exactly the error you see on windows, so in `Database_open`, use following to open the file:

```
if(mode == 'c') {
    conn->file = fopen(filename, "wb");
} else {
    conn->file = fopen(filename, "rb+");
    if(conn->file) {
        Database_load(conn);
    }
}
```

This will also work on Linux because are files are binary mode on Linux.

Comment: "open failed, errno 2: No such file or directory" - so conn->file is NULL

Comment: yeah, that means the file does not exist, so please check if the file is there.

Comment: The file is there. It was created by fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file); and it quite happily opens in Vim. The screen shot shows it listed in the directory as "-rw-r--r-- 1 myUserName Administrators 2 Apr 14 10:53 db.dat" So, permissions problem then?

Comment: If it was the permission problem, errno would say something about permission, not no such file. I think it's something else.

Comment: ex17.exe | db.dat -- why is there a "|" on the command line?

Comment: The character is a lower case L. I've set up MinGW on my Windows machine, so I can use Linux like commands i.e.   ls -l

"I think it's something else." The r+ in "conn->file = fopen(filename, "r+")"?

Comment: hmm, you said it was created by fwrite, but fopen with r+ will not create the file, it will fail if the file does not exists, you may need w+ or a+.

Comment: Well ... DB files are created by two function calls Database_create(conn); and then Database_write(conn); Databasewrite does this

rewind(conn->file);
int rc = fwrite(conn->db, sizeof(struct Database), 1, conn->file);

If fopen uses w+ then there will be the problem of the user mistakenly creating files he missed typed e.g. when adding a new entry:
ex17.exe bd.dat s 2 user@myDomain.com

w+ would create a 2nd file named bd.dat - not add a new entry to db.dat (p.s. - system security at work will not let me chat)

Comment: What I mean is fwrite does not create files, so we can only work this by fopen.

Comment: uh-ah! C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\learn_c>ex17.exe c test.dat
open failed, errno 2: No such file or directory
Failed to open the file.: No such file or directory

C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\learn_c>ls -l test.dat
ls: test.dat: No such file or directory

Comment: yeah, sounds on the right track :)

Comment: The line to create the file is conn->file = fopen(filename, "w"); I've tried w+ and a+. However, still "No such file or directory" error happens for both of them. Does fopen need the full path I wonder? Checking now.

Comment: hmm, please post your complete code, that's the only way we could find out what's going wrong.

Comment: The code is a bit too long. If you go to http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html you'll see the code I'm studying from.

Comment: Ok, in Database_open, it creates and possibly overwrite the file if action is 'c', for all other actions, it open it with "r+". So try first create the db by calling the program with ex17 db.dat c, then ex17 db.dat s to set, l to list etc

Comment: I can create the test.dat, but I cannot access it afterwards. 

C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\learn_c>ex17.exe test.dat c

C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\learn_c>ls -l test.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 userName Administrators 103201 Apr 14 12:42 test.dat

C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\learn_c>ex17.exe test.dat s 1 user
user@myDomain.com
ERROR!  Failed to load database.

C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\learn_c>ls -l test.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 userName Administrators 103201 Apr 14 12:42 test.dat

Comment: are you running the same code as on the webpage?

Comment: I'm mostly running the same code on the "Learn C the Hard Way ex17" page. That site's code is for Linux machines, but C is C (for the most part) Sorry for the late reply. I'm at work.

Comment: Just noticed that Database_close was completely typed wrong, so the file was not being closed properly. I've fixed it but still same errors

Comment: for s action, the expected argc should be 6, right? but you are exiting when if it is not 4:  `if(argc != 4) { die("Id, name, and email address are needed."); }`

Comment: Good eye. Fixed that. But still same error :-(

Comment: hmm, works ok for me, if you just copy the sample program given on the page, will it produce the same error?

Comment: one thing I noticed to the size of sizeof(struct Database) is one less than the size of the db.dat file. ex17.exe db.dat s 1 user user@myDomain.com
sizeof Database  103200 + 1 = 103201
rc: 0
ERROR!  Failed to load database.

ls -l db.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 k3812 Administrators 103201 Apr 14 15:46 db.dat

 Adding 1 to sizeof(struct Database) when using fread didn't make a difference

Comment: That's the wrong way to look at it, try the sample program.

Comment: No dice - same errors :-(

Comment: It's quitting time for me. Thank you very much for your help today. I'm certain I'll see the mistake first thing tomorrow when my brain is fresh.

Comment: no problem, let me check it on windows, because it works just fine for me on Linux/gcc.

Comment: This is just an extra care you need to take on windows, the difference of text and binary mode of files. Updated my answer, choose it as accepted if you find it resolve your issue, after this long debug!

Comment: Hurrah! It worked. Thank you ever so much for you great effort.